# Non-overlapping implementations trip coherence rule?

Tags: rust

In my [optional](https://crates.io/crates/optional) crate, I wanted to implement `Eq` for all pre-declared types, and allow users to opt in, too, by having their types declare `Eq`. So I wrote:

```
impl<T: Noned + Copy + Eq + PartialEq> Eq for Optioned<T> {}
impl Eq for Optioned<f32> {}
impl Eq for Optioned<f64> {}
```

However, rustc complains with `E0119`, stating that I've run afoul of the coherence rules.

My `Optioned<T>` is defined as `pub struct Optioned<T: Noned + Copy> { value: T }`. The `Noned` trait is pre-defined for all number primitives.

Now, neither `f32` nor `f64` implement `Eq`, so I would have thought the impls be strictly non-overlapping. Can someone

- explain *why* the coherence rules trip me up and
- tell me how to change my code to make it work anyway?

Comment: I believe that https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23086 (under the header "Hazards arising more specifically from negative reasoning") answers your first question, but I'm afraid I can't think of a good solution.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, this appears to be the issue. So I guess the correct solution is to either implement this for every single type or wait until the developers either implement specialization or negative trait bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, neither f32 nor f64 implement Eq, so I would have thought the impls be strictly non-overlapping.

The problem stems from the fact that you don't control the types `f32` or `f64`. The implementors of those types (in this case, the language itself), could choose to implement `Eq` for those types *in the future*.

If that were to happen, then your code would just suddenly start failing when you updated the crate the types came from (or the language, in this case). In order to prevent that, Rust disallows this construct. To my knowledge, there is no workaround.